# first occurrence code binary search debug in c

Tags: arrays, c, binary-search, find-occurrences

```
int firstOcc(int a[],int m,int x)
{
    int high=m-1,low=0,mid,index=-1;

    while(low<=high){
    mid=(low+high)/2;

    if(a[mid]<x){
        mid=low+1;}

    if(a[mid]>x){
        mid=high-1;}

    if(a[mid]==x){
        index=mid;
        high=mid-1;}
    }

    return index;
}
```

why is my function isn't working ?! finding first occurrence. what is wrong with it ?

can't find the bug, copied almost identical code from the internet it worked but I need to know why my code isn't working

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/11082165)

Comment: There are multiple bugs here.  First, you should never change `mid` in a given iteration after setting it at the top of the loop.  Instead, you need to set `low` or `high`.  The assignments to `mid` after the first are dead code, since it is redefined at the top of each loop iteration.  Second, you really should use `else if` and `else`.  Otherwise you're doing unnecessary work.

Comment: Is your input in sorted order? That's a precondition for using binary search.

Comment: Do apply conventional indentation to your code.  That would make it far easier to read, probably even for you, yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong:

```
        mid=low+1;}
…
        mid=high-1;}
```

right:

```
        low=mid+1;}
…
        high=mid-1;}
```

`mid` change is off the table.